# Compare directory just by name and size of content

Tags: linux, files, file-copy

I want to compare the content of two hard drives and I'd like to verify that each and every file and folder that exists in one drive exists in the other drive as well and ***simply has same name and size***.

I already saw answers to similar questions but they all either compare *names only* (which is not enough) or use `rsync` and compare also dates and permissions, which I really don't care about.

I also want to avoid completely comparing file contents as it would take too much time, verifying that each file has same name and size is enough for me.

Comment: Does the name matching go right down to the / (root) directory on each file system (or the only file system on the drive), or does it end up behind a mount point? This seems to need 3 checks: (1) No file on A is missing from B. (2) No file on B is missing from A. (3) No file on both A and B has a different size. I phrase those in the negative because if some script tells me "There is a mismatch", my one-second response is "Prove it, show me!". Also, folder sizes can be affected by previous actions (like growth and deletes) and their size is not significant.

Comment: The name matching should start after "/media/myuser/drive1/" and "/media/myuser/drive2/". Everything after this should match. The 3 steps you mentioned describe exactly what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: This is a classic use case for [`mtree`](https://github.com/archiecobbs/mtree-port/wiki/Downloads).